# Hmm estimation in R

Tags: estimation

Im trying to studie likelihood estimation of the transition and emission matrices of an Hmm via a sequence of observation provided from 2 hidden states and 3 possible values at each state

## using SeqHmm to generate the sequence

```
#déclaration des matrices de transition et d 'emission

P.trans <- t(matrix(c(0.2,0.8,
                      0.7,0.3),nrow=2,ncol=2))

P.emiss <- t(matrix(c(0.2,0.6,0.2,
                      0.3,0.5,0.2),nrow=3,ncol=2))


# simuler un hmm avec la fonction du package seqHMM
sim <- simulate_hmm(n_sequence=1,transition_probs = P.trans,
                    emission_probs = P.emiss, initial_probs = c(1/2,1/2),
                    sequence_length = 100)

# transformer les observations comme un vecteur numeric 

sim.obs <- as.numeric(gsub('\\-', ' ', sim$observations))
```

## using Hamilton's 1988 to calculate the log-likelihood function

```
llh <- function(p,y){

  # matrice de transition de la chaine cachée
  trans.mat <- matrix(c(1-p[1],p[1],
                          p[2],1-p[2]), nrow=2, ncol = 2,byrow = TRUE)

  # matrice d'émissions
  emiss.mat <- matrix(c(p[3],1-p[3]-p[4],p[4],
                          p[5], p[6],1-p[5]-p[6]), nrow=2,ncol=3,byrow = TRUE)

  # la longueur de la chaine

  T <- length(y)
  Pr <- numeric(T)

  #distribution initiale
  V <- c(1/2,1/2)

  # calcul de la vraisemblance
  for(c in 1:T){
    w = numeric(nrow(trans.mat))
    #i = Y[c-1]
    j = y[c] 
    for (k in 1:nrow(trans.mat)) {
      w[k] = 0
      for (l in 1:nrow(trans.mat)) {
        w[k] = w[k] + V[l]*trans.mat[l,k]*emiss.mat[l,j]
      }
    }
    Pr[c]= sum(w)
    V=w/sum(w)
  }

  # on ajout le - pour minimiser la fonction au lieu de la maximiser
  bjf = -sum(log(Pr))
  return(bjf)
}
```

## using optim the minimize the - log-likelihood function

```
prob.init.optim <-c(0.5,0.1,0.3,0.4,0.3,0.7)

# lancer optim

optim(par=prob.init.optim, fn=llh, y=sim.obs)
```

it returns a negative probabilities values !! does any one can help ?

Comment: Then, your question is documented but isn't about code Amirouche, you might get more and better answers posting it at [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).